# defining custom DataTemplates and assign them to the ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to get into Xamarin development and followed Microsofts video tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPXVqdRXZms&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oU10SXt2W58pu2L0v2dOW-1&index=9

Currently I would like to populate my `ListView` with some basic labels. So first the following code works fine for me. I created a custom `ViewCell` and assign it to the `ListView` as the `ItemTemplate`

```
public class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListView MasterPageNavigationItemsView { get; }

    public MasterPage()
    {
        // ...

        MasterPageNavigationItemsView = new ListView()
        {
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MasterPageItemViewCell()),
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None
        };
        MasterPageNavigationItemsView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(MasterViewModel.MasterPageItemsCollection));

        // ...
    }
}

internal class MasterPageItemViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public MasterPageItemViewCell()
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(MasterPageItem.Title));

        View = label;
    }
}
```

I would prefer to create a custom `DataTemplate` as they did in the video tutorial. I found the code on Github

https://github.com/codemillmatt/xamarin-101/blob/8271814c7ebdd41387e20ed33b3dfbdcd54409be/coded-ui-navigation/CodedUINav/Views/MainPage.cs#L88-L112

So instead of doing `ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new MasterPageItemViewCell()),` I would like to do `ItemTemplate = new MasterPageItemTemplate(),`

which results in the class

```
internal class MasterPageItemTemplate : DataTemplate
{
    public MasterPageItemTemplate() : base(LoadTemplate)
    {
    }

    private static Label LoadTemplate()
    {
        Label titleLabel = new Label();
        titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(MasterPageItem.Title));
        return titleLabel;
    }
}
```

So I took the code from Github and modified it a little bit. When I run the code the labels content is empty and when I click on it the application crashes.

How can I fix the `MasterPageItemTemplate`?

---

**Update**

I found another sample that makes use of view cells

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListview/WorkingWithListview/Custom

so I think I should follow this and use this code for now

```
ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MasterPageItemViewCell)),
```

Comment: your LoadTemplate method returns a Label, but the caller does nothing with it

Comment: @ Jason thanks but the Github example does the same, no? I thought when passing the `LoadTemplate` function to the base constructor it will be called and processed

Comment: Is it helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data items in a `ListView` are called `cells`. Each cell corresponds to a row of data. There are built-in cells to choose from, or you can define your own custom cell. Both built-in and custom cells can be used/defined in XAML or code.The child of an inline `DataTemplate` **must be** **of**, or **derive from**, type **Cell**.Here in your first link sample, the `ListView.ItemTemplate` property is set to a `DataTemplate` that's created from a custom type that defines the cell appearance. The custom type derive from type `ViewCell`,but in your codes custom `DataTemplate` return a `Label`,it will not work.

you could refer to [Creating DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating#creating-a-datatemplate-with-a-type)

And in the sample of your second link,it use `CollectionView`.You could nest markup inside a `DataTemplate` tag to create a View.

**Note** :When using `CollectionView`, **never set the root element** of your `DataTemplate` objects to a `ViewCell`. This will result in an exception being thrown because CollectionView has no concept of cells.